# convert groupby to dataframe, join the groups again

Tags: python, pandas

Global groupby object was created from local dataframe

```
self.grouped = df.groupby('name')
```

I need to get the dataframe from this groupby object => inverse operation to df.groupby()

Is there any better way than this?

```
print pd.concat([group[1] for group in self.grouped]).sort_index()
```

Comment: if you just want the original object, e.g. the groupee (say you don't have the reference anymore), then ``self.grouped.obj`` is it

Comment: Great, where is this documeted? I have not found it! http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/api.html#groupby
Make this as an answer please.

Comment: certainly welcome a pull-request to add to this proposed internals page: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4082

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the original object from a `DataFrameGroupby` object like this:

```
self.grouped.obj
```

This is an internal attribute (its 'public', but not documented). Most of the passed in options to `groupby` are set as attributes of the returned `DataFrameGroupby` object as well (this applies to all of the `NDFrameGroupby` objects, just showing the most common returned object).

Comment: this isn't that useful as it will throw away any changes made in modifying the groups?

Answer (score 1):

You can do `self.grouped.apply(lambda x:x)`

Incidentally, this also lets you modify each group after doing a `groupby` and then ungrouping again to get the result.